# Why isn't my custom event firing?

Tags: c#, events

I'm making an app to log user inactivity and am having problems with a couple of custom events, no exceptions are thrown and no compiler errors come up, but when I run my application nothing writes to the console, which makes me think the event isn't firing at all! I've told the event to show a message if it pops up but nothing happens, which I believe confirms my suspicions.

I'm not an expert in C# or Custom Events, so any and all help would be greatly appreciated =]

my code for my custom events is below;

```
             Inactivity inact = new Inactivity();
             inact.Active += inactivity_Active;
            inact.Inactive += inactivity_Inactive;

     public void inactivity_Inactive(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            var logdata1=Inactivity.GetIdleTime();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(logdata1);
            MessageBox.Show("Inactive");
        }

        public void inactivity_Active(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var logdata2 = Inactivity.GetIdleTime();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(logdata2);
            MessageBox.Show("Active");
        }
```

these are the methods that are going to be called in order to raise the active and inactive events

```
    public void OnInactive(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler inactiveEvent = this.Inactive;
        if(inactiveEvent!=null)
        {
            inactiveEvent(this, e);
        }
    }


   public void OnActive(EventArgs e)
   {

       EventHandler inactiveEvent = this.Inactive;
       if (inactiveEvent != null)
       {
           inactiveEvent(this, e);
       }
       }
```

Comment: It seems that OnActive(EventArgs e) method is copy-pasted from OnInactive(EventArgs e) method. Do you really want two identical methods or it's a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Inactivity inact = new Inactivity();
```

That is not how you define an event. You define an event like this:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Active;
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Inactive;
```

And you raise those events by writing/calling these methods:

```
protected virtual void OnActive(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<EventArgs> active = Active;
    if (active != null)
    {
        active(this, e);
    }
}

protected virtual void OnInactive(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<EventArgs> inactive = Inactive;
    if (inactive != null)
    {
        inactive(this, e);
    }
}
```

Your event handler methods are correct. For reference, I have repeated them here:

```
public void inactivity_Inactive(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var logdata1=Inactivity.GetIdleTime();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(logdata1);
    MessageBox.Show("Inactive");
}

public void inactivity_Active(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var logdata2 = Inactivity.GetIdleTime();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(logdata2);
    MessageBox.Show("Active");
}
```

You would register those to be called when the respective event is raised with this code, which you could place into the constructor of that class, for example.

```
Active += inactivity_Active;
Inactive += inactivity_Inactive;
```

Comment: I was about to write this! He was missing the protected virtual void method. Good answer. Here it´s microsoft´s example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16.aspx

Comment: How do I then handle the event? =] thanks for the good answer btw!

Comment: I have edited my answer to make that more clear. Basically, your event handler methods were already fine, they just need to be registered properly so they get called when the events are raised.